# How to organize builds by project and sub-project in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

We currently use TFS for source control and TeamCity for CI/CD, and we have over 300 builds. We are looking to possibly migrate to Jenkins, but I'd like to know if builds in Jenkins can be organized by project and sub-project.

For example, in TeamCity our builds are organized by Project, then by sub-project (branch), and then by builds:

`Project1
    Dev
        build1
        build2
    Test
        build3
    Release
        build1
        build2
        build3
Project2
    Dev
        build1
    Test
        build2
    Release
        build1
        build2
Etc.`

Can this type of organization be done in Jenkins?

If not, then we would have to name our builds something like `Project1_Branch_build1`, and have a long flat list of 300+ builds in Jenkins.

Comment: Take a look at the [multi branch pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Multibranch+Plugin) and [this post](https://jenkins.io/blog/2015/12/03/pipeline-as-code-with-multibranch-workflows-in-jenkins/)
Does what you want I think

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it appears that the Pipeline Multibranch plugin only supports Git and Subversion, not TFS as source control.